flutter unit test failing
This test keeps failing
    ProviderContainer createContainer(
    {ProviderContainer? parent,
    List<Override> overrides = const [],
    List<ProviderObserver>? observers = const []}) {
  final container = ProviderContainer(
      parent: parent, overrides: overrides, observers: observers);

  addTearDown(() => container);

  return container;
}

@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<AuthRepo>()])
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  late MockAuthRepo mockAuthRepo;

  setUp(() {
    mockAuthRepo = MockAuthRepo();
  });

  test(("test initial state"), () {
    final loginNotifier = createContainer();
    expect(loginNotifier.read(loginProvider).status, Status.initial);
  });

  test(("test successful login"), () async {
    final container = createContainer(overrides: [
      loginProvider.overrideWith((_) {
        return LoginNotifier(authService: mockAuthRepo, ref: _);
      })
    ]);

    when(mockAuthRepo.login(any)).thenAnswer((_) async {
      return {
        "token": "testtoken",
        "data": {
          "completedProfile": 30,
          "user": {"id": "123456"}
        }
      };
    });

    await container.read(loginProvider.notifier).login(AuthRequest());

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      expectLater(container.read(loginProvider).status, Status.loading);
    });
  });
}

with the error
Expected: Status:<Status.loading>
Actual: Status:<Status.initial>
i have tried moving the call to the provider call up and down. removed await, added await, increased the time of the Future.delayed all of these did not work.
